# Adding header with value django cores

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

According to the [django-cors-header](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/) documentation in order to add custom headers you add:

```
  CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + ('my-custom-header',)
```

To your `settings.py`, question is how do you add my-custom-header along with it's value to settings.py.

Comment: What exactly is do you mean when you say "how do you add my-custom-header along with it's value" please elaborate

Comment: e.g 'Content-Type: application/json'

Answer (score -2):

`CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS` is a list of headers that can be used while making actual request

Following setting does not set header values that can be used, just headers that can be used in requests

Also `content-type` is already in default_headers so it doesn't need to be set as extra

```
 CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)
```

To explain more on your comment

CORS package is used to give a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) issued from browser ( OPTIONS method ) answer on questions regarding which/if method or headers are accepted on the following server

Comment: I already know Content-Type is in the defaults. I was explaining what I wanted. Unless you are saying in essence there is no way to set a default value for headers.?

Comment: @acquayefrank correct, added more explanation on my answer